# Scheme error "except: misuse of unit import keyword"

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I'm writing a function that returns elements which appear in one list and not in another. For example,

```
(except '(a b c) '(a d b e f))
```

will return `'(c)`. The first argument can be an atom, and both are assumed to be flat. Here's my code:

```
(define (except lm ln)
  (cond ((null? ln) lm)
        ((not (list? lm))
         (cond ((in? lm ln) '())
               (#t lm)))
        ((null? lm) '())
        ((in? (car lm) ln) (except (cdr lm) ln))
        (#t (cons (car lm) (except (cdr lm) ln)))))
```

Then an error returns saying "except: misuse of unit import keyword in: (except (cdr lm) ln)".

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running into some problem with the [unit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_unit.html) library which has an [`except`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingunits.html#%28form._%28%28lib._mzlib/unit..rkt%29._except%29%29) keyword defined.  But it should still be possible to use it as a name for your function, so I'm guessing that something else is wrong.  It'll be possible to say more if you provide the complete code that you're trying to run.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. In fact this was all the code that I typed in after I launched DrRacket, so I'm also confused.

Comment: It's important to kno *exactly* where you typed it: in the top definitions window or in the bottom interactions window?  It's also important to know if there was any text before what you added (for example, some `#lang` line)?  And finally, it's important to know what are you language settings (both).  But SO is not really a support forum, so it'll be better to ask your question on the [mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html) or on IRC (#racket) etc.