# Scheme: "expects 1 argument, given 4" odd behavior

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

To implement depth-first search in a grid, I wrote a function like this

```
(define (expand dim node visited obs)
  (not-in (neighbor dim obs node) visited))
```

The function dfs is

```
(dfs dim obs visited fringe path goal)
```

The only appearance of *expand* in *dfs* is

```
(expand dim (car fringe) visited obs)
```

And I called *dfs* using

```
(dfs '(5 5) '((2 2) (3 2)) '((2 1)) '((1 1) (3 1)) '((2 1)) '(4 5))
```

*dim* is the dimension of the grid, *obs* is a list of the blocked positions in the grid.

When I call *expand* by hand it works perfectly. But when it's called in *dfs*, it says "*expand: expects 1 argument, given 4: '(5 5) '(1 1) '((2 1)) '((2 2) (3 2) (3 4) (4 4) (5 4))*"

However, if I change the position of arguments of *expand*, e.g. put *obs* as the second argument,

```
(define (expand dim obs node visited)
  (not-in (neighbor dim obs node) visited))
```

and modify *dfs* and my callings correspondingly, then the error won't appear and everything works well. Then next time I launch DrRacket and paste the modified code into it, the same error reappears. If I swap *obs* back, it works well again...
What on earth is happening here?! Thanks!

Comment: Please write the code for the other procedures so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know: are you putting all your definitions into a single file, or have you put them in separate modules?  Are you in `#lang racket`, or in one of the teaching languages?  The problem you're describing sounds as though Racket thinks it should be using the `expand` function from its standard library, rather than the one that you've defined.  We need more context to diagnose what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expand` is an awfully generic name that might have a definition somewhere else. Rename your funciton to `dfs-expand` and see if this fixes it.

Comment: This would most likely fix it, but it avoids resolving the problem that causes it.

Comment: Unless the problem that causes it is that he has two functions named `expand`! ;-)

Comment: Unlikely.  See my pointer: s/he had the same problem with a different builtin, and still didn't explain precisely what s/he's doing.

Comment: I still have no idea what the problem and solution to this is.  The original author accepted an answer, but after reading the entry, I still have no idea what just happened.  If the OP can please explain what just happened, that will be **really** helpful to others on Stack Overflow who encounter similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the same problem you're having in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338460/).  As is the case there, `expand` is a function that is already defined in Racket, but writing your own definition should still work fine.  So like I said there, you should describe *exactly* what you're doing to know why you have these problems in the first place.